# When to destroy Google AdMob InterstitialAd object?

Tags: unity, c#, performance, admob

There are [a](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial) [few](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/72) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865578/memory-goes-on-increasing-each-time-the-interstitial-ad-is-display-in-unity-5) on this question but they don't give a satisfactory answer.

I am using a singleton AdManager class that persists throughout the game. I am not sure if I should destroy the instance of InsterstitalAd each time after displaying an ad. This [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/psImCBZFWsw) says that an InterstitalAd object can only be used once, however in my current implementation I use the same instance multiple times without any ill effect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private string InterstitialAdId = "test-code";
    public static AdManager Instance = null;

    void Awake()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => {});
        RequestInterstitialAd();
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;

        // Singleton class
        if (Instance == null) {
            Instance = this;
        } else if (Instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) {
        DisplayInterstitialAd();
    }

    public void RequestInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(InterstitialAdId);
        interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnInterstitialAdClosed;
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
   }

    public void HandleOnInterstitialAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
    }   

    public void DisplayInterstitialAd() {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }
    }

    public void DestroyInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialAd.Destroy();
    }
}
```

As I understand the InterstitalAd object refers to a UI element, while the actual content of the ad comes from AdRequest, so I can reload the ad content without affecting the InterstitalAd object. **Do I need to call DestroyInterstitalAd() after each time after an ad is displayed?** I want to prevent any memory leaks from happening during long plays.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you don’t *see* any ill effects doesn’t mean you’re doing everything right. Destroy your interstitial ads. [Google’s example implementation](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/blob/master/samples/HelloWorld/Assets/Scripts/GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript.cs) does this before loading the next ad:

```
private void RequestInterstitial()
{
    //...

    // Clean up interstitial ad before creating a new one.
    if (this.interstitial != null)
    {
        this.interstitial.Destroy();
    }

    // Create an interstitial.
    this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    //...
}
```